# Jquery, select appended ul inside ul

Tags: jquery

i am quite new to jquery and i want to select an element that is being appended inside a list.

here is the html code after append:

```
<!-- Show all folders in the directory -->
<ul data-level=".">
    <li>
        <a href="" class="folder">Angular</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="folder">Html</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" class="folder">PHP</a>
        <!--this is appended-->
        <ul data-level="./PHP">
            <li>
                <a href="">BankSimulation</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
```

and here is the js file:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.folder').parent().on('click', function()
    {
        var selector = this;
        var dir = $(selector).parent().attr('data-level') + '/' + $(selector).text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'init.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                dir: dir,
                JSON: true
            },
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data)
            {
                appendList(selector, data);
            },
            error: function(error, errorCode, errorThrown)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    function appendList(selector, list)
    {
        var level = $(selector).parent().attr('data-level') + '/' + $(selector).text();

        $(selector).append('<ul data-level="' + level + '">' + encodeToLiTag(list) + '</ul>');
    }

    function encodeToLiTag(element)
    {
        var summary = '';
        for(data in element)
        {
            var link = element[data];
            summary += '<li><a href>' + link + '</a></li>';
        }

        return summary;
    }
});
```

i do not find the reason why it is not working, the code seems to be a little simple, but i do not know if the event is not working because it is being appended

Comment: How about making a JSfiddle for the problem.. then you can get the answer fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the click event on DOM ready. At that time the nested ul does not exist. So, no event is bound to them when they are added. That's why the code won't work for nested ul because the event is not fired for the nested ul after they are added.

To get over this problem you have to use event delegation (read event delegation part from [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-events/)).

Basically you will bound the click event to the parent/root ul.

```
$('ul[data-level=\\.]').on('click',function(e){
    var selector =  e.target;
    var dir = $(selector).parent().parent().attr('data-level') + '/' + $(selector).text();
    console.log(dir);
});
```

<kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ec3abgzo/)</kbd> given.

Comment: your answer was the solution, i never worked with the parameter of the function and that made the work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)`:

```
var selector = $(this);
```

Comment: it selects the first ul, and not the nested ul

Comment: $(this) will give the object of the clicked anchor tag with class folder. Using just this you cannot use parent() method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to your list is appended inside your hyperlink.

```
<li>
 <a href="" class="folder">Angular
   <ul data-level="./Angular">
     <li><a href="" class="folder">Apple</a><li>
   </ul>
 </a>
</li>
```

When you have the code above, when you click the "Apple", it will call the event of "Angular", because "Apple" is consider part of "Angular"

Rather than append it to the hyperlink, i'm appending the list next to the hyperlink. Thus it won't cause the wrong event trigger.

```
<li>
 <a href="" class="folder">Angular
 </a>
 <ul data-level="./Angular">
   <li><a href="" class="folder">Apple</a><li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Besides that, I also change the event from "on" to "click" to avoid event attaching to the wrong selector. I will only add the event when the list is append.

Please find the sample code at the link below:
http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/boe1yjsh/1/

Hope this help :D